# How is this commode style toilet seat called in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests

As I am disabled, I thought, in case my Appartment doesn't have a western style toilet, I might want to buy one of these:
[image]

So I wonder what they are called and where one could hope to buy them. If the university provides free Appartments I thought it impolite to insist on a Western style toilet.

Comment: [大便椅子／可折叠式老人厕所座椅／拉屎凳子／孕妇马桶坐便器椅](https://world.taobao.com/item/540012233179.htm?fromSite=main)／／／[座椅式馬桶](http://www.taobao.com/product/座椅式馬桶.htm)

Comment: The squat position is better for your health! As a Chinese who now live in Canada, I miss this kind of toilet.

Comment: @zyc my country uses the same system and it has many advantages, but not for disabled people 殘疾人 such as I am!

Comment: @Ludi Sorry I didn't know. Wish you can find a good one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**坐便椅** can be the name you want, in a decent way.

In addition you can find it in [Aliexpress](https://s.taobao.com/search?q=%E5%9D%90%E4%BE%BF%E6%A4%85). Some big pharmacies also offer these.